# ERROR:gpu_init.cc(441)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled in Cypress

Tags: electron, cypress

After updating cypress to 8.6.0, the following error message started appearing when I run the `test cases --headless`.

> ERROR:gpu_init.cc(441)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled

After doing some research, I believe this issue may be related to Electron. When I run the cmd `navigator.userAgent` in the console of my Electron Browser I get the following information:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
> like Gecko) Cypress/8.6.0 Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Electron/14.1.0
> Safari/537.36

It seems both Chrome and Electron are outdated for the Electron broswer in the Cypress's test runner.

Running the same cmd in Google Chrome I get:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
> like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36

My gut feeling is if I get the Electron broswer to the latest 15.1v the issue may not appear, any clue how I should go about this or any alternative methods to resolve this issue?

thank you!

Comment: I was getting this error as the path to `preload.js` was incorrect in my case.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue.
I followed first this page https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/18947.

Finally, the only thing that worked for me was to delete the package C:\Users....\AppData\Roaming\Cypress

I still don't know why this happend. My collegues don't have this issue.

Comment: Thank you, this resolves the issue incase anyone is wondering.

Answer (score 3):

I do not have a solution, but I think I can answer one of your questions.

I have the same issue and if nothing else, perhaps a bit more information might point us both to a potential solution.  In my Electron application which did not previously push this error, I updated Node, Angular, Typescript, and Electron while I was installing Quill for an editor component.  The Node install had me upgrading my Python library as part of the "additional tools" because of VS Studio (I assume).  That set of updates is when this error started showing up.

My new versions are:
Angular: 12.2.10
Node: 14.18.1
TypeScript: 4.3.5
Electron: v15.2.0

The actual error I get is somewhat different (it appears to be truncated):

> [23968:1018/192434.788:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(453)] Passthrough is not
> supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is

I hope that something here jives with someone as I would like to fix this console error as well.  I hope this helps.  Please post back if you solve this.

In any case, no, updating to Electron 15 will not fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The issue stopped occurring for me after Cypress's latest update (Version 9.0.0)

Comment: I still get this issue in Cypress v9.0.0

Comment: I just started using Cypress again after a break, npm installed version 8.7.0, get `Opening Cypress...` then this error. I am not using Electron for my app. I don't even get the Cypress UI launching, :-(

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by updating nodejs ( windows 10 )

Answer (score 0):

My problem in electron was fixed after updating my `npm start` command to run like the below added option in package.json.

```
   "scripts": {
        "start": "electron . --dev --use-angle=swiftshader",
```